# Call function from plugin in template

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

In craft 2 I had a simple plugin that I used to run some php code. I could call the function like this.

```
{{ craft.pluginname.functionname }}
```

However I have been unable to do the same thing in craft 3. I have created a new plugin for craft 3. Moved my functions to the main plugin file in src.

Is there a new way to call a function from a plugin in craft 3?

**Ok got it figured out.**

author below = root plugin path in vendor folder

In main plugin file had to add

```
use author\pluginname\variables\variablename;
use craft\web\twig\variables\CraftVariable;
```

Updated init event to

```
Event::on(
    CraftVariable::class,
    CraftVariable::EVENT_INIT,
    function (Event $event) {
        /** @var CraftVariable $variable */
        $variable = $event->sender;
        $variable->set('pluginname', variablename::class);
    }
);
```

Created variables file in variables folder src/variables/variablename.php

```
namespace author\pluginname\variables;
use author\pluginname\mainClassName;
use Craft;

class variablename
{
    //Custom Functions Here
    public function test() {
        echo 'Test';
    }
}
```

Then from a template I was able to use

```
{{ craft.pluginname.test }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to register your variable in your plugin's `init()` method, like this:

```php
Event::on(
    CraftVariable::class,
    CraftVariable::EVENT_INIT,
    function (Event $event) {
        /** @var CraftVariable $variable */
        $variable = $event->sender;
        $variable->set('pluginname', PluginVariable::class);
    }
);
```

c.f.: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/extending-twig.html

Comment: Ok did that, looks like there is more to it than this... viewed another plugin I installed from app store. Created a variables directory with the variables file. Added use pluginroot/pluginname/variables/pluginvariable How do you call it using twig from a template file? Seems to be way more involved than craft2 apparently.

Comment: I might have just figured it out, will update later if I did, sorting out other deprecated errors.

Comment: Got it figured out, will update original post with more info on how I got it to work... for anyone else with same issue. Not a lot detailed docs on this stuff...

Comment: You can generate your plugin scaffolding at https://pluginfactory.io and it'll do all of this for you